# evt.target.result is undefined, how can I encrypt blob?

Tags: javascript, blob

I want to encrypt mp4 file that was posted by php file. So, I get mp4 file in blob and I want convert blob to String because of encrypting data.

I'm trying to get blob using readAsBinaryString with evt.target.result and I don't know why this output is undefined. Please help me solving this problem. Here's the source code!

```
var mp4text;
var reader = new FileReader();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '111', true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type : "video/mp4"});
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            mp4text = evt.target.result;
            mp4text = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(mp4text, "test");
            mp4text = mp4text.toString()
            var myBlob = new Blob([mp4text], {type : "video/mp4"});
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
            document.getElementById('myVideo').src = downloadUrl;
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        console.log(this.response);
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.getElementById('myVideo').src = downloadUrl;
    } else {
        alert('Unable to download mp4.')
    }
}
xhr.send('id=1');
```

here's the debug info

https://mail.naver.com/file/download/each/?attachType=normal&mailSN=103&attachIndex=2&virus=1&domain=mail.naver.com&u=fnclovers' width= '310'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially you need to update type of the blob. You do it for the 2nd blob but not the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! But, I add type of blob and It doesn't working too. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I solved! This is the problem that I didn't consider the limit of file size!